# How to hook into <head></head> container

Tags: loop, post-meta, wp-head

I want to add my own `<meta />` tag inside the `<head></head>` container on every page or post within the `loop()`.

Is that possible?

What hook(s) should I use for that?

Comment: [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head)

Answer (score 4):

to hook in the `<head>` you would use `wp_head`. [You can read the documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head).

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'meta_example' );

function meta_example() {

    echo '<meta name="description" content="Meta Description for this Page." />';

} // End meta_example()
```

This assumes that your theme has `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in the `<head>`.